# bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-native' from '/workspace/reactnative''

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I updated `react-native` to v0.57 and `react-native run-ios` is failing. I replaced `babel-preset-react-native` with `metro-react-native-babel-preset` as suggested in https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-native. here is the error stack trace I am getting.

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-native' from '/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative'
- If you want to resolve "react-native", use "module:react-native"
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:58:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePreset (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:58:10)
    at loadPreset (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:77:20)
    at createDescriptor (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at items.map (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/buraktas/workspace/reactnative/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "react-native-branch": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-deep-linking": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-fabric": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.22",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.1.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "stripe-client": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^3.2.0",
    "detox": "^9.0.4",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.6.0",
    "jest-cli": "^23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "airbnb",
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "module:react-native",
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `package.json` it looks like all you have done is upgrade the version of react-native to the latest version.

Unfortunately it is not as simple as changing the version number in the `package.json`. You don't state which version of react-native you were using before, but as you are using `React 16.2.0` I would hazard a guess that you were on react-native 0.52 or 0.53.

To upgrade you should look at the diff that is provided between your version and the version that you upgrading to. `rn-diff-purge` shows the changes between that need to be performed. For upgrading `0.52.0` to `0.57.8` you can see the changes [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.52.0...version/0.57.8), for `0.53.0` to `0.57.8` you can see the changes [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.53.0...version/0.57.8).

You can check the changelog https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md to see more specific requirements for upgrading between the versions.

It is also worthwhile looking at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading for tips on how to perform an upgrade.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Yeah you were right we were using react-native 0.52 and I tried to update versions incrementally, however, I faced some issues. Meanwhile, we decided to keep our current version until we need to update it. But since I am not going to spend more time on this issue I will accept this change since you have included very helpful links. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Deleting .babelrc file will fix this for you.

Please check react native upgrade helper

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper

and specify your current React native version and the version to update (0.57 in your case)

You will see changes need to do in your case to make the code compatible with updated version

[image]