# React Native tests failing, missing babel transforms

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I want to test a React Native application that I've created based on the [default guides](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html), so it's very simple and has not had any changes w.r.t. the initial test configuration. The only difference seems to be that it's using `npm` instead of `yarn` (so it has a `package-lock.json`).

Here is the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "license-checker": "^25.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The test file `__tests__/App-test.js` is very simple (and auto-generated):

```js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

I get this error:

```
➜ npm test
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /node_modules/@foo/bar/src/main.js:24
    export function milliseconds(timeoutInMilliseconds) {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Now, I don't really understand why it wouldn't work "out of the box". [Other guides](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native) mention the same steps, too.

Adding a `.babelrc` with:

```js
{ 
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

produces the error:

```
Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-native' from '/'
    - If you want to resolve "react-native", use "module:react-native"

      at Function.module.exports [as sync] (node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:74:15)
      at resolveStandardizedName (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
      at resolvePreset (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:58:10)
      at loadPreset (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:77:20)
      at createDescriptor (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
      at node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at createDescriptors (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
      at createPresetDescriptors (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
      at presets (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
```

There is already a `babel.config.js` file with the following contents (as suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/431)):

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

What should I do? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196147/bundling-failed-error-cannot-find-module-babel-preset-react-native-from-wo) but the React App has not been upgraded and is not missing anything, AFAICT. Note that when I create a completely new app with the init script, the tests run fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `"react-navigation": "^4.0.10"` which uses `react-native-gesture-handler`. Jest does not know about it. You have to mock `react-native-gesture-handler` and add `react-navigation` to `transformIgnorePatterns` or use [`react-native-jest-mocks`](https://github.com/Xabadu/react-native-jest-mocks).

Some examples of mocking `react-native-gesture-handler` can be found here: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/344

Add `"files": ["jest/setup.js"],"` inside `package.json`. Also `transformIgnorePatterns` must include `react-navigation-stack`, `@react-native-community`, `react-native-gesture-handler` and `react-navigation`.

`package.json`:

```js
"files": [
  "jest/setup.js"
],
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "setupFiles": ["./jest/setup.js"],
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/"
  ],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation-stack|@react-native-community|react-native-gesture-handler|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*)"
  ]
}
```

`jest/setup.js`:

```js
import { NativeModules as RNNativeModules } from "react-native";
RNNativeModules.UIManager = RNNativeModules.UIManager || {};
RNNativeModules.UIManager.RCTView = RNNativeModules.UIManager.RCTView || {};
RNNativeModules.RNGestureHandlerModule = RNNativeModules.RNGestureHandlerModule || {
  State: { BEGAN: "BEGAN", FAILED: "FAILED", ACTIVE: "ACTIVE", END: "END" },
  attachGestureHandler: jest.fn(),
  createGestureHandler: jest.fn(),
  dropGestureHandler: jest.fn(),
  updateGestureHandler: jest.fn(),

};
RNNativeModules.PlatformConstants = RNNativeModules.PlatformConstants || {
  forceTouchAvailable: false
};

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

Now run jest and it should pass the test. I have created a repo with an example RN 0.61 app using `react-navigation` that has jest test passing: https://github.com/clytras/RNJestTest

Or you can try [`react-native-jest-mocks`](https://github.com/Xabadu/react-native-jest-mocks) but I haven't tried it with RN 0.61 yet.

Comment: Thanks! It was just impossible for me to read about this anywhere… I did get a bit farther with that, now I get an error in `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/warnOnce.js:15`: `SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rcWW.png — any idea?

Comment: @slhck check the updated answer. I have uploaded on Github a very simple example repo that works, check it out.

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution. I now get a different error, but I know why. It's weird that this is so poorly documented; you'd think it could pick all that up more or less automatically.